# How to convert the following JSON string into a dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert the following JSON response string into a C# Dictionary<string,string>

```
{
  {
  "type": "Select",
  "name": "timezone",
  "label": "Timezone",
  "description": "Select the city closest to you that shares your same timezone.",
  "multiOptions": {
    "US/Pacific": "(UTC-8) Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "US/Mountain": "(UTC-7) Mountain Time (US & Canada)",
    "US/Central": "(UTC-6) Central Time (US & Canada)",
    "US/Eastern": "(UTC-5) Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
    "America/Halifax": "(UTC-4)  Atlantic Time (Canada)",
    "America/Anchorage": "(UTC-9)  Alaska (US & Canada)",
    "Pacific/Honolulu": "(UTC-10) Hawaii (US)",
    "Pacific/Samoa": "(UTC-11) Midway Island, Samoa",
    "Etc/GMT-12": "(UTC-12) Eniwetok, Kwajalein",
    "Canada/Newfoundland": "(UTC-3:30) Canada/Newfoundland",
    "America/Buenos_Aires": "(UTC-3) Brasilia, Buenos Aires, Georgetown",
    "Atlantic/South_Georgia": "(UTC-2) Mid-Atlantic",
    "Atlantic/Azores": "(UTC-1) Azores, Cape Verde Is.",
    "Europe/London": "Greenwich Mean Time (Lisbon, London)",
    "Europe/Berlin": "(UTC+1) Amsterdam, Berlin, Paris, Rome, Madrid",
    "Europe/Athens": "(UTC+2) Athens, Helsinki, Istanbul, Cairo, E. Europe",
    "Europe/Moscow": "(UTC+3) Baghdad, Kuwait, Nairobi, Moscow",
    "Iran": "(UTC+3:30) Tehran",
    "Asia/Dubai": "(UTC+4) Abu Dhabi, Kazan, Muscat",
    "Asia/Kabul": "(UTC+4:30) Kabul",
    "Asia/Yekaterinburg": "(UTC+5) Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent",
    "Asia/Calcutta": "(UTC+5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, New Delhi",
    "Asia/Katmandu": "(UTC+5:45) Nepal",
    "Asia/Omsk": "(UTC+6) Almaty, Dhaka",
    "India/Cocos": "(UTC+6:30) Cocos Islands, Yangon",
    "Asia/Krasnoyarsk": "(UTC+7) Bangkok, Jakarta, Hanoi",
    "Asia/Hong_Kong": "(UTC+8) Beijing, Hong Kong, Singapore, Taipei",
    "Asia/Tokyo": "(UTC+9) Tokyo, Osaka, Sapporto, Seoul, Yakutsk",
    "Australia/Adelaide": "(UTC+9:30) Adelaide, Darwin",
    "Australia/Sydney": "(UTC+10) Brisbane, Melbourne, Sydney, Guam",
    "Asia/Magadan": "(UTC+11) Magadan, Soloman Is., New Caledonia",
    "Pacific/Auckland": "(UTC+12) Fiji, Kamchatka, Marshall Is., Wellington"
  }
}
```

Using Newtonsoft JSON library, I cannot figure out how to do this. Using online converters, it creates a class called MultiOptions, and then puts all of those as properties.

Comment: I don't see how your JSON can be possibly converted to a `Dictionary<string,string>`. What string would correspond to the key `multiOptions`? i.e. what _string_ would I get if I access `jsonDict["multiOptions"]`?

Comment: Here's my thought process, and feel free to tell me that I'm insane or it just can't be done:
Take all those key/value pairs underneath multiOptions: {, and remove the commas at the end, and change the colons to commas... and then add to dictionary?

Does this make sense? I am not sure if I am explaining it right

Comment: Do you just want to convert everything under `multiOptions` to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, and ignore things like `type`, `name` and `label`?

Comment: Yes please! That is what i am looking for.

Comment: You pasted invalid json. Correct it.

Comment: I repeat: this is invalid json. The number of opening and closing curly brackets does not match. Fix the error!

Comment: The @knowonecanknow user gave the correct answer. It works if you fix your incorrect json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible , you need to use System.Reflection

```
public Root MyDeserializedClass = new Root();
public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
...
private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ConvertToDictionaryPair();
}

private void ConvertToDictionaryPair()
{
   PropertyInfo[] properties = MyDeserializedClass.multiOptions.GetType().GetProperties();
   foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
   {
       string key = property.Name;
       string value = property.GetValue(MyDeserializedClass.multiOptions).ToString();
       if (!MyDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
           MyDictionary.Add(key, value);
   }
}
```

Model

```
public class Root
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public MultiOptions multiOptions { get; set; }
    }

    public class MultiOptions
    {
        [JsonProperty("US/Pacific")]
        public string USPacific { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("US/Mountain")]
        public string USMountain { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("US/Central")]
        public string USCentral { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("US/Eastern")]
        public string USEastern { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("America/Halifax")]
        public string AmericaHalifax { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("America/Anchorage")]
        public string AmericaAnchorage { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Pacific/Honolulu")]
        public string PacificHonolulu { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Pacific/Samoa")]
        public string PacificSamoa { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Etc/GMT-12")]
        public string EtcGMT12 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Canada/Newfoundland")]
        public string CanadaNewfoundland { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("America/Buenos_Aires")]
        public string AmericaBuenosAires { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Atlantic/South_Georgia")]
        public string AtlanticSouthGeorgia { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Atlantic/Azores")]
        public string AtlanticAzores { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Europe/London")]
        public string EuropeLondon { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Europe/Berlin")]
        public string EuropeBerlin { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Europe/Athens")]
        public string EuropeAthens { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Europe/Moscow")]
        public string EuropeMoscow { get; set; }
        public string Iran { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Dubai")]
        public string AsiaDubai { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Kabul")]
        public string AsiaKabul { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Yekaterinburg")]
        public string AsiaYekaterinburg { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Calcutta")]
        public string AsiaCalcutta { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Katmandu")]
        public string AsiaKatmandu { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Omsk")]
        public string AsiaOmsk { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("India/Cocos")]
        public string IndiaCocos { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Krasnoyarsk")]
        public string AsiaKrasnoyarsk { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Hong_Kong")]
        public string AsiaHongKong { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Tokyo")]
        public string AsiaTokyo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Australia/Adelaide")]
        public string AustraliaAdelaide { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Australia/Sydney")]
        public string AustraliaSydney { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Asia/Magadan")]
        public string AsiaMagadan { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Pacific/Auckland")]
        public string PacificAuckland { get; set; }
    }
```

First click on Get Data and populate the model , then click set data , and iterate through the model and add each property name and value to the dictionary.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L11fE.png)

Comment: Why xaml? Why GUI Why http? Question about json deserializing.

Comment: i know , its just I didnt know the expertise(since they're a new contributor) of the person asking the question so i just copy pasted the entire flow, if and when they accepts/replies it , I'll shorten it @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 2):

You can give Newtonsoft a DTO to deserialize into.

```
var parsedDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParsedJsonResponseDto>(jsonResponse);
```

Where the DTO object looks something like.

```
public class ParsedJsonResponseDto
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("multiOptions")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> MultiOptions { get; set; }    
}
```

Now that you have an object with your dictionary of MultiOptions you can iterate over however you like.

Comment: When I do this, I get an InvalidCastException  @knowonecanknow